# Open source and commercial tools to build dynamic queries of fact tables in star schema

Tags: tools, facttable, dimension, star-schema

What user interfaces or tools (commercial and/or open source) can query a star schema model (Ralph Kimball dimensional model)?  So for example, if we have X fact tables, and Y dimension tables, and Z cross reference tables, we'd like to query a random fact table.  If you are aware of such tools, can you provide a reference of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mondrian OLAP server 
http://mondrian.pentaho.com/

Pentaho Schema Workbench (for creating the cube schema)
http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/workbench.php

Pentaho Aggregation Designer (for finding useful aggregations and building them)
http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Faggregation_designer_guide%2Fconcept_pad_overview.html

Saiku AJAX pivot tables
http://analytical-labs.com/

[Pentaho Report Designer](http://reporting.pentaho.com/report_designer.php) for designing reports.

Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) for ETL into data warehouse
http://kettle.pentaho.com/

[DataCleaner](http://www.datacleaner.org/) for quality control

Answer (score 1):

We are familiar with the IBM toolset where I work. [IBM's Cognos toolset](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/cognos/enterprise/) can read star schema, especially since IBM recommends star schema for mart design.